# Increment the Prime Key Field Value Everytime Query Appends Other Fields

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, append, record

In my database named 'ADMS', there exists a table called 'Merit' with fields:

(**Index**, Merit List Number, Group, OM, AS, AR, FGEI, RFGEI, Session)

*Index is the Prime Key* with Data Type as 'AutoNumber'

I want to add a new record in all field through a form named 'Update Merit' which has:

2 combo combo-boxes called MeritListVal and Group Val;

the rest objects are all Text Boxes which include SessVal, OMVal, ASVal, ARVal, FGEIVal, RFGEIVal, DPVal.

Now, what i want is to add new records into the table Merit through the Form 'Update Merit';

i tried the following SQL Code;

```
INSERT INTO Merit ( [Merit List Number], [Group], [OM], [AS], [AR], [FGEI], [RFGEI], [DP], [Session] )

VALUES ( [Forms]![Update Merit]![MeritListVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![GroupVal]. [Forms]![Update Merit]![OMVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![ASVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![ARVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![FGEIVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![RFGEIVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![DPVal] );

SELECT Merit.[Merit List Number], Merit.[Group], Merit.[OM], Merit.[AS], Merit.[AR], Merit.[FGEI], Merit.[RFGEI], Merit.[DP], Merit.[Session]

FROM Merit;
```

> It is giving me Error: Number of Query Values and Destination Fields is not the Same.

Is it because of the PrimeGrpKey?

Is it putting an increment when the Append Query INSERTs Values into it?

If not, how to i make it increment everytime a new record is added?

What would be the SQL Code to perform this task?

**Even after i deleted the *Index* Field it is still not adding more records, same error.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Insert Into Merit has 9 column names
Your Value section has 8 column names

This is why there is a error.

[image]

Add another value at the "values" section of your code.  My guess is "[Forms]![Update Merit]![SessionVal]".

Comment: i know.. but how do i make it increment the the **Index** while it also appends other records?

Comment: It doesn't allow to create a table without a primary key

Comment: all the other field records except Index field values will be repeated, so i had to set something as primary key

Comment: Your error is not due to a primary key violation.  The Index will auto increment up a value for each insert.  This will keep the record unique.  https://www.microassist.com/software-tips/access-tip-using-the-autonumber-data-type-in-access/  Your error is due to your mismatch in columns expected and provided.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: or a solution, at least?

Comment: `INSERT INTO Merit ( [Merit List Number], [Group], [OM], [AS], [AR], [FGEI], [RFGEI], [DP], [Session] )       
VALUES ( [Forms]![Update Merit]![MeritListVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![GroupVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![OMVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![ASVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![ARVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![FGEIVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![RFGEIVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![DPVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![SessVal] )        
SELECT Merit.[Merit List Number], Merit.[Group], Merit.[OM], Merit.[AS], Merit.[AR], Merit.[FGEI], Merit.[RFGEI], Merit.[DP], Merit.[Session]
FROM Merit;`

Comment: Now, it's giving 'Characters found after end of SQL Statement

Comment: now what? just for you to know, this is a competition at my college and i have to present this at 21st Oct..

Comment: Not sure I can help you with the new error.  I was able to spot your previous error pretty quick. I'd ask a Access expert as to why the new error is happening.  Google the error message and see what other people are doing to resolve the error.  Good luck on your competition.

Answer (score 0):

> The New Error: Characters after end of SQL Statement

received after @QuestionGuyBob's Answer to the Missing Field Error is because in this Code;

```
VALUES ( [Forms]![Update Merit]![MeritListVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![GroupVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![OMVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![ASVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![ARVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![FGEIVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![RFGEIVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![DPVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![SessVal] );

SELECT Merit.[Merit List Number], Merit.[Group], Merit.[OM], Merit.[AS], Merit.[AR], Merit.[FGEI], Merit.[RFGEI], Merit.[DP], Merit.[Session]
FROM Merit;
```

Turns out, There's no need to use SELECT Statement after INSERT INTO Statement.
So, the previous code becomes;

```
INSERT INTO Merit ( [Merit List Number], [Group], [OM], [AS], [AR], [FGEI], [RFGEI], [DP], [Session] )

VALUES ( [Forms]![Update Merit]![MeritListVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![GroupVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![OMVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![ASVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![ARVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![FGEIVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![RFGEIVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![DPVal], [Forms]![Update Merit]![SessVal] );
```

And now, it is successfully appending Data into multiple fields of the Table 'Merit'
Thank you @QuestionGuyBob for pointing out the initial Errors.